# How to access asp hiddenfield value from UserControl in Javascript (getElementByID not working)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, hiddenfield

So I've gotten stuck trying to access a HiddenField value in my UserControl from my JavaScript.

In my user control I have:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

This user control is used in multiple places and sometimes multiple times on the same page so ClientIDMode = Static is not an option, and it must be runat = server as I need to access it in the code behind as well.

In my JavaScript I have tried the following:

```
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
document.getElementById('HiddenField1');
$find("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>");
```

All of these return null. I have seen a number of "solutions" suggest

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1')
```

But that obviously poses problems for re-usability.

EDIT:
The html generated by this is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$$ctl00$SomeUserControl$someOtherUserControl1$HiddenField1" id="MainContent_MainContent_SomeRepeater_SomeUserControl_0_someOtherUserControl1_0_HiddenField1_0" value="353">
```

The value is set in the code behind through other functions.

EDIT2: Generalised my code example

Comment: right click and `view source` of the web page. check whether you are able to see the hiddenfield input item. then now copy the `id` from there and try getElementById for it.

Comment: when you view source, what is value of `document.getElementById('<%= hfInsuranceCompanyID.ClientID %>'); ` ? is it not properly giving ClientID?

Comment: could you paste the html generated by your control in the question, we have a alot of jquery selectors which can be used.

Comment: I've edited the original post Gagan

Comment: @Matt: what about `document.getElementById('<%= hfInsuranceCompanyID.ClientID %>');` not giving expect output?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking Shivaji. I've already tried that but it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make this work with hidden field and so I caved and just changed my object to an asp:Label with a CSSClass and stored the value in the text property.

Not the best solution I know, but if anybody has a better suggestion please let me know.

Comment: There were no other suggestions so sadly this has to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind may be your code look like this

```
public void test()
{
   hdnvalue.Value = "Test";
    //After assign the value you should call client side function
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Script", "<script 
   language='javascript'>gethidden()</script>", false);
}
```

In javascript function should use like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function gethidden() {
    var hdn = document.getElementById('<%=hdnvalue.ClientID%>');
    alert(hdn.value);
 }
</script>
```

I hope its help to you.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion however I need to access it all client side. The purpose of this is to perform an AJAX call and improve performance on the page (the view state is incredibly large in this project so postbacks need to be minimised).

Comment: Hi., you have mentioned "The value is set in the code behind through other functions." your are assigning value in server side means, above code useful to you.

Comment: Hello Angappan.S, the code above doesn't work for my purposes because the value is only set at page_load in code behind, but needs to be accessed client side after the user interacts with other objects on the page. This is all to avoid a postback and improve performance of the page. Postbacks are not feasible.